# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: export-to-excel, excel-interop

I am working on the application, and emport the report to Excel sheet. When I do that on my project this is working fine.But, when I run this application on IIS 7( Windows 7 64-bit) it gives me below mentioned errors -

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied.

I have tried lot of solutions available online, but with no use. Please suggest me what could be the problem and also solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was facing the same problem, it could be either of the following reasons :

1. The DLL required for the Excel you are using is not present.
2. Different versions of Excel on different servers.
3. Permission Issues

Please let me know what issue might be in your case, may be I could help you.

Comment: Hi there, I have the similar issue but not with the excel or any Microsoft Office objects. I'm trying to use a COM object via my ASP Net Core application and having this error message with different CLSID. What would you suggest?